# UML: How to select Activities when drawing activity diagrams?

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram, modeling

Hi
I wanna to know that what key points do you consider when drawing activity diagrams for selecting "Activities"?
How do you pick activities from a problem you want to model it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity diagram is used to model the workflows of your system under development and related systems. So in your problem space you need to identify the workflows required to solve your problem. For example, you may need to develop a timesheet system, one workflow might be to submit a timesheet, so the activities might be: fill in hours, post on web page, then the next activity may split into two parallel activities, such as create invoice, log sales information, notify manager.

Note that the activities can be carried out by human or systems.